# Reflection of a particle from step potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

[image]

Suppose the boundary of the step potential is at x=0.

Suppose there is a particle emitter located some distance away from the step potential.

Suppose that at time t=0, a particle of definite energy E (where E < potential height) is emitted by the particle emitter towards the step potential.

Now, when solving the Time Independent Schrodinger wave equation, we find that the solution for x<0 corresponds to a combination of two plane waves moving towards the right and the left. The solution for x>0, corresponds to an exponentially decaying wavefunction.

My question is, at time t=0 when the particle is emitted from the emitter, do we consider the entire wavefunction at the same time t=0? (as shown in the figure)

It does not make sense because if the emitter is located far away from the step potential, then the emitted particle should take some finite time to reach the step potential. Therefore, initially, the wavefunction should be zero at the boundary of the step potential.

Comment: When solving the time-independent SE you find a basis of stationary states that are eigenstates of the total energy allowed by the system. When creating the wave function for a specific case, e.g. a particle emitted from a source, you implement this mathematically by demanding a certain initial shape of the wave function at time $t=0$. Then you can evolve the wave function in time with the time evolution operator.